# Multiple Access To security cameras

Tags: authentication, camera, video-streaming, ip-camera

There are systems in which security cameras are connected to data centers (Workstation computers, constantly observed by human operatives). I am simply talking about ordinary security systems.

There are 4 possible cases in such architectures:

1) Multiple cameras - single data center, 
2) Multiple cameras - multiple data center, 
3) Single camera - singe data center and
4) Single Camera - multiple data center.

Assume that cameras only have pan - tilt - zoom + real time video streaming functionality.
For "case 2" systems, there are some issues:
- What will happen when two data centers want to access the same camera at the same time.
- Is there any priority hierarchy between data centers?
- Is there any proiority hierarchy between actions (Ex. Pan-tilt has precedence over version query)
.
.
.

I think those issues must be so common among security systems developers, are there any ALGORITHMS, SPECIFICATIONS, BOOKS or LIBRARY implementations - for multiple access to Security Camera Systems ??

Currently I am examining ONVIF Specification, but I couldn't manage to find any related definitions.

I am aware that my question is too general but any help will become handy.

Answer (score 0):

Try out this for showing different camera

> ```
>   <title>Video Camera</title>
>
>   <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"
> ```
>
> > 
>
> ```
>   <style type="text/css" media="screen">
>     video {
>       border:1px solid gray;
>     }
>   </style>   </head>   <body>
> <script>
>   if (!MediaStreamTrack) document.body.innerHTML = '<h1>Incompatible Browser Detected. Try <strong
> ```
>
> style="color:red;">Chrome Canary instead.';
>
> ```
>   var videoSources = [];
>
>   MediaStreamTrack.getSources(function(media_sources) {
>     console.log(media_sources);
>     alert('media_sources : '+media_sources);
>     media_sources.forEach(function(media_source){
>       if (media_source.kind === 'video') {
>         videoSources.push(media_source);
>       }
>     });
>
>     getMediaSource(videoSources);
>   });
>
>   var get_and_show_media = function(id) {
>     var constraints = {};
>     constraints.video = {
>       optional: [{ sourceId: id}]
>     };
>
>     navigator.webkitGetUserMedia(constraints, function(stream) {
>       console.log('webkitGetUserMedia');
>       console.log(constraints);
>       console.log(stream);
>
>       var mediaElement = document.createElement('video');
>       mediaElement.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
>       document.body.appendChild(mediaElement);
>       mediaElement.controls = true;
>       mediaElement.play();
>
>     }, function (e) 
>     {
>       alert('Hii');  
>       document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('hr'));
>       var strong = document.createElement('strong');
>       strong.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(e);
>       alert('strong.innerHTML : '+strong.innerHTML);
>       document.body.appendChild(strong);
>     });
>   };
>
>   var getMediaSource = function(media) {
>     console.log(media);
>     media.forEach(function(media_source) {
>       if (!media_source) return;
>
>       if (media_source.kind === 'video') 
>       {
>         // add buttons for each media item
>         var button = $('<input/>', {id: media_source.id, value:media_source.id, type:'submit'});
>         $("body").append(button);
>         // show video on click
>         $(document).on("click", "#"+media_source.id, function(e){
>           console.log(e);
>           console.log(media_source.id);
>           get_and_show_media(media_source.id);
>         });
>       }
>     });
>   }
> </script>   </body> </html>
> ```